# Get option value of disabled option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have one option disabled in select tag

```
       <div class="form-group required">
          <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Status</label>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
             <select class="form-control validate-required" id="employee_status">
           <option value="">Select Status</option>
           <option value="Reinitiated" disabled="">Reinitiated</option>
           <option value="Suspended">Suspended</option>
           <option value="Terminated">Terminated</option>
           <option value="Resigned">Resigned</option></select>
   <small id="employee_status_help" class="text-danger hide">Status is required</small>
    </div>
 </div>
```

I have tried to the below to fetch the value of disabled option

```
          inputvalue = $('#employee_status option[disabled]:selected').val();
```

It is not working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `inputvalue = $('#employee_status option[disabled]').val();` it should do the trick

I've tried it like this and it appears that ':selected' is not valid so it returned undefined

You probably wanted to use `::selection` but that selects the portion of an element that is selected by a user

You can see my code bellow

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    inputvalue = $('#employee_status option[disabled]').val();
    console.log(inputvalue);
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="form-group required">
          <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Status</label>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
             <select class="form-control validate-required" id="employee_status">
           <option value="">Select Status</option>
           <option value="Reinitiated" disabled="">Reinitiated</option>
           <option value="Suspended">Suspended</option>
           <option value="Terminated">Terminated</option>
           <option value="Resigned">Resigned</option></select>
   <small id="employee_status_help" class="text-danger hide">Status is required</small>
                      </div>
                  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

That is because the disabled option is not selected. So remove `:selected`

```js
var inputvalue = $('#employee_status option[disabled]').val();

console.log(inputvalue);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group required">
  <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Status</label>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <select class="form-control validate-required" id="employee_status">
           <option value="">Select Status</option>
           <option value="Reinitiated" disabled="">Reinitiated</option>
           <option value="Suspended">Suspended</option>
           <option value="Terminated">Terminated</option>
           <option value="Resigned">Resigned</option></select>
    <small id="employee_status_help" class="text-danger hide">Status is required</small>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

But the `disabled` option cannot be `selected`

You only need this:

```
$('#employee_status option[disabled]').val();
```

```js
console.log($('#employee_status option[disabled]').val());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group required">
  <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Status</label>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <select class="form-control validate-required" id="employee_status">
           <option value="">Select Status</option>
           <option value="Reinitiated" disabled="">Reinitiated</option>
           <option value="Suspended">Suspended</option>
           <option value="Terminated">Terminated</option>
           <option value="Resigned">Resigned</option></select>
    <small id="employee_status_help" class="text-danger hide">Status is required</small>
  </div>
</div>
```